# Arduino ethernet shield cant connect to IP

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I bought an Ethernet shield three days ago, but I have problems with internet connection. I can't access the IP address of the shield. I know the basics of Arduino and networking, but I don't have many experience with Ethernet shield.

I have Arduino UNO and Ethernet Shield W5100

Here is the code I am using:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
 Serial.begin(9600);


  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
   Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
    // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
    // so you can send a reply
    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be                       

      closed after completion of the response
      client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically             

      every 5 sec
      client.println();
      client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
      client.println("<html>");
      // output the value of each analog input pin
      for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        client.print("analog input ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(sensorReading);
        client.println("<br />");
          }
          client.println("</html>");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
      // you're starting a new line
      currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
      // you've gotten a character on the current line
      currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
      }
    }
```

Here is the Error:

```
server is at 192.168.1.177
new client
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.177
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8                       
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X)                                                                                                               

AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14D27
Accept-Language: sk-sk
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

client disconnected
```

Comment: There is no route existing between the PC and the device.  Use cmd.exe to help get things working use >IPCONFIG/All to get the PC IP and mask.  then use PING to help get things working.  you probably will either have to change the IP address, mask, or modify the settings of you local HUB to get a route

Comment: Let me know how to do this. I just got my IP and Subnet mask. And also DNS. But how to ping and let me see how to do the ping and how to get route between arduino and router. Please help

Comment: From cmd.exe > Ping IP X, where x is either the IP address or Machine Name.  You can get help >Ping/?

Comment: I Hope this will help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998745/direct-connection-between-laptop-and-arduino-via-ethernet